# java mongodb near query

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

User collection:

```
"userID":"1",
"location" : [ 
        77.667248, 
        13.0258562
    ],
 "latlong" : {
        "type" : "point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            77.667248, 
            13.0258562
        ]
    },
```

Java query:

```
 Query mongoQuery1 = new Query();
            mongoQuery1.addCriteria(Criteria.where("latlong.coordinates").near(point));
            mongoTemplate.find(mongoQuery1, User.class,"places");


  Query mongoQuery2 = new Query();
            mongoQuery2.addCriteria(Criteria.where("location").near(point));
            mongoTemplate.find(mongoQuery2, User.class,"places");
```

I am using above two java queries to get nearby users but getting exception like this below.I have created 2dsphere index also on user collection.

Exception:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.geo.Point] to type [org.bson.Document]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194)
```

while inserting user object to collection at this time i am getting same exception

```
org.springframework.data.geo.Point point = new Point(12.885970,77.656180);
 User u=new User();
 u.setUserID("123");
 u.setPoint(point);
 mongoTemplate.insert(u,"places");
```

Please help me.Thankyou.

Comment: For some classes in Mongo you have to set up a converter. You must search the web for a converter that works with the org.springframework.data.geo.Point class.

Comment: @Veeram please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Query q=new Query(Criteria.where("userID").ne(null));
        q.with(new PageRequest(user.getPaginationNumber(),2));
                             //longitude          //latitude
        Point p=new Point(user.getLoc().get(1),user.getLoc().get(0));
        NearQuery n=NearQuery.near(p);
        n.spherical(true);
        n.inKilometers();
        n.maxDistance(16); //16 kms
  n.num(10); //return only 10 objects
  n.query(q);

        GeoResults<User> results=mongoTemplate.geoNear(n,User.class,"User",User.class);
```